# DAX Running Difference

Tags: dax, powerbi

In Power BI I have a table column with decimal numbers.

How to create a new column with the running difference of the aforementioned column values?

See my personal example in the picture below:
[image: DAX Running Difference]

In this example I want `Column` to be the difference between the current value of `RunningExtraTime` and the previous one.

Comment: A running total makes no sense without some order of the base table. What field would this running total be sorted over?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than DAX, I would Edit the Query to resolve this, using a technique based on adding an Index column.

I assume you use "Add Index Column" and leave the default column name: "Index" and Step name: "Added Index". Then you can use "Add Custom Column" and refer to the prior row's value from column: "RunningExtraTime" using something like:

`= if [Index] > 0 then [RunningExtraTime] - #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[RunningExtraTime] else 0`

Answer (score 0):

is it associated with any time dimension? If yes then you can use any time intelligence functions like YTD or something like this in CALCULATE  DimDate[Datekey] <= MAX( DimDate[Datekey]).

You can of course calculate this in SQL (if database is your data source) or in Power Query (read [here](http://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/31/create-running-totals-in-power-query/))

Comment: Hi, No there is no time dimension here. It is just a number. Any thoughts?